# Adobe connect stuck on connecting

Tags: windows, server, adobe, windows-server-2012

I installed adobe connect and configured on a server and I have a domain, It's all connected and working, I can create meetings and every thing, but when I try to get in to a meeting I can't and adobe connect application stuck on connecting. I opened 443,80,1935 ports on server and I tried connecting even with firewall off but I had no luck, what else should I do on server?

Answer (score 1):

try to delete Internet Explorer cache and cookies . Follow these steps :

```
 1. Open run box by pressing Windows key and “R” at the same time.
```

2. Type “inetcpl.cpl” in the run box and hit OK.
3. Click on General tab and under browsing history section click on “Delete”.
4. Under Delete Browsing History window, make sure Temporary Internet files, Cookies     and History is checked.
5. Click on Delete and relaunch the meeting room.

   Additional Information:

   You can try launching the same meeting from other web browsers as well if they are available.

Comment: I did what you said but in a client computer it didn't work